# Retrieve file uploaded in Laravel using JavaScript FormData

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Running into a bit of trouble trying to upload multiple files through a single AJAX request into a Laravel 5 back-end.

In the front-end, I am using the following code to prep the FormData object:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("data", JSON.stringify(values));
fd.append("page_id", page_id);
files.forEach(function(file, index){
    fd.append("file_"+index, file);
});
```

Then this is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/file_test',
    data: fd,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response){
        alert(response);
    },
    failure: function(response){
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

In the back-end, I've tried to retrieve with `$request->allFiles()` and `$request->file('file_0')`  as well as `$_FILES` but they are all turning up empty.

---

After @Pavel mentioned that the `$_FILES` array was empty, I went and checked what was being sent up in the XHRRequest. What I realized was that I was not appending the file itself to the FormData object and instead was appending the whole `input` containing the file.

```
var files = [];
if(this.type == "file"){
    if(this.files.length == 1){
        values[$(this).attr('name')] = this.files[0].name;
        //files.push(this); // ORIGINAL CODE
        files.push(this.files[0]); // WORKING CODE!
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you manually will var_dump the `$_FILES`? Is it empty?

Comment: Yep, empty as empty can be!

Comment: Found the error, was incredibly silly. I wasn't pushing the files themselves into the `files` array, instead I was pushing the whole `input` object in there. Placing my answer in the original. Thank you for looking into this @Pavel

Comment: @Neurax give him a vote up then :)